# Why do my Elasticsearch integration tests only work sometimes

Tags: java, elasticsearch, junit, integration-testing

I have the following integration test:

```
public class TestElasticIT extends ESIntegTestCase {
  private static final String esIndex = "test";
  private static final String esEntityType = "entity";
  private static final String esDetailType = "details";
  private Client client = null;

  @Before
  public void beforeTests() throws Exception {
     XContentBuilder xContentBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject().startObject(esEntityType).endObject().endObject();
     XContentBuilder xContentBuilder2 = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject().startObject(esDetailType).startObject("_parent").field("type", esEntityType).endObject().endObject().endObject();

     client = ESIntegTestCase.client();
     createIndex(esIndex);

     client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping(esIndex).setType(esDetailType).setSource(xContentBuilder2).get();
     client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping(esIndex).setType(esEntityType).setSource(xContentBuilder).get();
  }

  @Test
  public void testCreateAndRead() throws Exception {
     ensureGreen(esIndex);

     IndexResponse entityResponse = client.prepareIndex(esIndex, esEntityType).setSource(testJson).get(); //This could be any key/value json
     IndexResponse detailResponse = client.prepareIndex(esIndex, esDetailType).setSource(testJsonDetail).setParent(entityResponse.getId()).get();

     //I want to see both parent and child here
     System.out.println(client.prepareSearch().execute().actionGet());
  }  
}
```

The problem that I'm having is `client.prepareSearch().execute().actionGet()` will only return my `testJson` every once in a while.  Sometimes it will work but most times it just returns nothing.  How can I get my integration tests to pass every time?

EDIT:
Queries that sometimes do and don't work:

```
client.prepareGet().setIndex(esIndex).setId(detailResponse.getId()).get();
client.prepareGet().setIndex(esIndex).setType(esDetailType).setRouting(esEntityType).setId(detailResponse.getId()).get();
```

Comment: There's a delay as new entries are parsed and indexed. I think your query is running before that process completes.

Comment: If you query the index manually, does the data show up?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to search. You should give search parameters in order to search. In case you want to check whether or not your index succeed you can use the method isCreated. If you want to perform a search operation over your database, give the requested parameter you want to search by.

Comment: So what I've been seeing is that the isCreated method will return true.  And even if I put a break point on the println and manually execute the search everything it won't return my json.

Comment: I think this might have something to do with the Randomized testing ES provides.  Or I'm not setting up the client correctly.

Comment: If I run a query client().prepareGet().setIndex(esIndex).setId(entityResponse.getId()).get().getSourceAsString() I successfully get back the json.  What am I doing wrong with the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a race condition, likely because you are not calling refresh() after creating the index, instead relying on ES to update before running a search request.

Since your class extends ESIntegTestCase you should be able to do something like

```
this.refresh(esIndex);
```

See these links for more information on this method in the test API:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/integration-tests.html
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/test/framework/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/test/ESIntegTestCase.java#L1186

This is also available in the main (non-test) Java API like so:

```
client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh(esIndex).get();
```

See here for more information on the Java API availability:
https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.3.0/org/elasticsearch/client/IndicesAdminClient.html#refresh(org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.refresh.RefreshRequest)

EDIT:

The first snippet I provided above only applies to the Elasticsearch 5.0 Alpha.  in current releases, the refresh method does not take an argument:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v2.4.0/core/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/test/ESIntegTestCase.java

Comment: Refresh doesn't seem to take an index.  Am I doing something wrong?  I call refresh(); right after createIndex(esIndex) but I'm still seeing the same behavior.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: What happens when you call the second code snippet I provided?  Looking back at github, it looks like the first snippet I supplied only applies to 5.0 alpha.

Comment: I verified that the first code snippet indeed applies only to the current alpha.  I have updated my answer to clarify.  When you mean "same behavior", it only works sometimes still, even after a refresh call (and after trying the second snippet I posted)?

Comment: Yea it still only works sometimes.  I've put both refresh() and client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh(esIndex).get() all over the place and it still sometimes fails to find the child.  The parent is always there.

Comment: To clarify if I search for the esEntityType json it always finds it but sometimes it is not able to find the esDetailType json.

Comment: Try putting a refresh after each of these lines: `IndexResponse entityResponse = client.prepareIndex(esIndex, esEntityType).setSource(testJson).get(); //This could be any key/value json` and `IndexResponse detailResponse = client.prepareIndex(esIndex, esDetailType).setSource(testJsonDetail).setParent(entityResponse.getId()).get();` and see if that works.

Comment: I tried putting them after pretty much every line all together and I'm still seeing the same behavior.  Although it's only on a prepareGet() for a esDetailType.  prepareSearch works everytime on both the esEntityType and esDetailType.

Comment: Hmmm.. The only thing I can think of is the `setRouting` call not being needed in that prepareGet, since you don't seem to be doing anything with sharding or interacting with shards directly.